# Parsing a fix length string and return object type in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, parsing, plsql

What I want to do is to parse an incoming string into record type and return it through function.for.e.g.

```
create or replace type parserecord as object (p_name varchar2(20),p_field varchar2(200),p_position number)
```

/

```
create or replace type parserecordtable as table of parserecord
```

/

```
create or replace function fparsetext(t_msg varchar2) return parserecordtable  
is  
    parserecorddata parserecordtable ;  
begin  
    parserecorddata := parserecordtable();  
    parserecorddata .extend(100);  
    parserecorddata (1) := parserecord ('A',substr(t_msg,1,1),1);  
    parserecorddata (2) := parserecord ('B',substr(t_msg,2,5),2);  
    parserecorddata (3) := parserecord ('C',substr(t_msg,6,8),3);  

   return parserecorddata ;  

end;  
/
```

This function would return the desired data...my problem is, instead of numeric index for type table, I want to use varchar2...i.e.

```
parserecorddata ('A') := parserecord ('A',substr(t_msg,1,1),1);    
parserecorddata ('B') := parserecord ('B',substr(t_msg,2,5),2);    
parserecorddata ('C') := parserecord ('C',substr(t_msg,6,8),3);
```

I tried changing the type definition of the table type to use 'index by varchar2(10)' but it threw error PS-00355

Any suggestion on what am I doing wrong?
Many Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Associative arrays can be defined within a PL/sql progmra only.

Comment: By default nested table indexes will starts from 1 to n and not possible to change index type. If u want to specify index type as varchar2 then go for associate arrays. But Associative arrays are not store at schema level. Means we can define associate arrays in pl/sql block only.

Comment: Thanks but would I be able to return assosiative array in a function once it is declared at packge level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to define an associate array indexed by string at the schema level, as per [this table from the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CIHHDDGF).

You could define the array at a package spec level and then use that to handle the results from your function, assuming you're not calling the function in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! This is what helped me to achieve based on the comments...